# MS Bot framework - Linking Message Controller and Calling Controller

Tags: c#, botframework, skype, skype-bots

I'm working on a Skype bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework. I have a MessageController and CallingController. I'm trying to somehow link the information obtained from the MessageController with a function within the calling controller.

e.g. Within the chat, a user enters their username and then they are then required to call and record their message. I would like to save their message with the entered username. I also need to somehow separate when multiple users are using the system at the same time.

I see within the Message there is the "context.Activity.Conversation.Id" but not sure if I can somehow get that same conversation ID within the Call.

Cheers

Comment: are you using the default state service or a custom state service?

Comment: AFAIK, using the default state service. Based off the bot framework documentation.